# How to display international boundaries in a OpenLayers map?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, boundaries

I'm interested in displaying **only** the boundaries, coastlines and between countries, of the world through OSM. I'm a bit lost and I don't know what I should do.

I'm trying to display the OSM through OpenLayers on a website.

This is how I displayed the map through OpenLayers

```
 var view = new ol.View({
    center: istanbul,
    zoom: 6
  });

  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        preload: 4,
        source: new ol.source.OSM() //OpenStreetMap here
      })
    ],
    // Improve user experience by loading tiles while animating. Will make
    // animations stutter on mobile or slow devices.
    loadTilesWhileAnimating: true,
    view: view
  });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. In what application are u looking at OSM data? Desktop GIS, webGIS? In short, you can download boundaries from OSM using different tools (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) and build your own map. You can also look at some map tile providers that may only display boundaries.

Comment: @juminet I'm trying to display the OSM through OpenLayers on a website.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Comment: I suggest indeed to put some code in order to help you.

Comment: @juminet I added it.

Comment: I have an answer but I cannot answer since it is 'on hold'. @utopia: Could you still improve the question: what kind of boundaries: national ones?

Comment: I'd edit the title like this: "How to display international boundaries in a OpenLayers map? "

Comment: @juminet Done, it is no longer on hold :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix the default rendering of OpenStreetMap (which is displayed at openstreetmap.org) and the OpenStreetMap database itself. Actually, you can use the OSM data to [create your own custom slippy maps](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/), but that's a big work.

One simple way to answer your question is to display your own layer of the boundaries of the world directly in OpenLayers. You can do it by putting a vector layer in your OpenLayers application:

```
// Add a boundaries layer
var geojsonSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  url: 'yourboundariesdata.geojson',
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
});

var geojsonLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  title: 'Boundaries',
  source: geojsonSource
});

map.addLayer(geojsonLayer);
```

where `yourboundariesdata.geojson` hold the boundaries data of the world. See [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495/seeking-administrative-boundaries-for-various-countries) on how to get such data, or [here](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php). You can transform the GIS data (e.g., in shp) to the geojson format using QGIS. If you are only intesrested in the boundaries of a few countries, you can get geojson layer per country at Mapzen [here](https://mapzen.com/data/borders/).

Another solution would be to replace the OSM source (in `ol.source.OSM()`) by another map provider. See https://mc.bbbike.org/mc/ for quickly comparing different map tile providers.

J.