# Selecting coastal census tracts in ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, adjacency

What tool should I use to select or identify geographic units that are adjacent to the U.S. coastline feature in ArcMap?

Answer (score 1):

The [Census cartographic boundary shapefiles](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_nation.html) do not include offshore areas. You could use a [Select by Location](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/using-select-by-location.htm) to look for tracts which intersect the cartographic boundaries. You'll need to account for tracts bounding Canada and Mexico; a few sources for administrative boundary files, such as gadm.org, are listed in [Seeking administrative boundaries for various countries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495)