# Seeking shapefiles for regions?

Tags: data

We are looking for shapefiles/geojson for below regions:

```
Africa Eastern
Africa Western
Africa Northern
Africa Middle
Africa Southern

Asia Southcentral
Asia Eastern
Asia Southeastern
Asia Western

Asia Central

South America
North America
Central America
Caribbean

Europe Eastern
Europe Western
Europe Southern
Europe Northern

Australia Australia and New Zealand
Australia Melanesia
Australia Polynesia
```

Where can I get combined/or individual regions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Seeking administrative boundaries for various countries?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/495/seeking-administrative-boundaries-for-various-countries)

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

I think you will struggle to find those regional shapefiles. But when i've needed country wide shapefiles, i tend to use Natural Earth:

http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/

In your case, i would download the "Admin 0 - Countries" file. If you then open this shapefile into, let's say QGIS or ArcMap, open the attributes table and it has categorised each country into regions and subregions:

[image]

Then just simply select features by subregion, and export this as a new shapefile:

[image]

In QGIS: Save vector layer as...
and make sure "Save only selected features" is ticked:

[image]